# Non-Hausdorff topological space where all retract subspaces are closed

Tags: general-topology

A retract subspace of a topological space $X$ is a subspace $A$ where there exists continuous $f: X\to A$ such that $f|_A = \mathrm{id}_A$. It is well-known that a retract subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed, and I'm concerning about the converse.

So, is there a non-Hausdorff example in which every retract subspace is closed?

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/191022 . Specifically, if you have a non-Hausdorff compact space where all compact subsets are closed, then you're done.

Comment: Following Paul Fabel's idea in the link above, just take the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$ to obtain a compact non-Hausdorff space, each of whose compact subsets is closed, and in particular each retract of which is closed.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! :)

Comment: @JianingSong You should now write an official answer to your own question. Spaces in which all compact subsets are closed are known as *KC spaces*. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2793040.

Comment: @PaulFrost Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to my own question. Following the thoughts from the comments, note that compact $\mathrm{KC}$ (every compact subset is closed) implies $\mathrm{RC}$ (all retracts are closed): a retract $A$ is the continuous image of the whole space which is compact, hence being compact (so closed).

It is well-know The one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$ is compact and $\mathrm{KC}$ but not Hausdorff, so it serves as a non-Hausdorff space where all retracts are closed.

(Now we can ask if the implication $\mathrm{RC}\Rightarrow \mathrm{KC}$ holds. I've posted the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434451/all-retracts-are-closed-and-all-compacts-are-closed).)

Comment: You should also accept your answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost OK, after 2 days as required.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524171 for the fact that the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$ is KC.